# How can I get yesterday's date in Venom?

Tags: yaml, venom

I am trying to use Venom to automate some API test, and I can use `{{.venom.datetime}}` to get the current date and time, like `2023-11-22T16:43:25-05:00`. But I would like to get something like `2023-11-21T00:00:00` and `2023-11-21T23:59:59`. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while there is no direct way to get that from the `venom` framework itself, but you can use `exec` steps for that.
See below examples where the date value is also stored in a var for being reused in subsequent steps

```
      - name: Get yesterday date start of day
        type: exec
        script: date -v -1d "+%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00Z"
        assertions:
          - result.code ShouldEqual 0
        info:
          "yesterday_start date is {{.result.systemout}}"
        vars:
          yesterday_start:
            from: result.systemout
      - name: Get yesterday date end of day
        type: exec
        script: date -v -1d "+%Y-%m-%dT23:59:59Z"
        assertions:
          - result.code ShouldEqual 0
        info:
          "yesterday_end date is {{.result.systemout}}"
        vars:
          yesterday_end:
            from: result.systemout
```

above shell commands are for mac, similar can be found for linux using `-d` param